# Fancybox stops working when invoked twice in the same browser session

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I have an odd problem with Fancybox. Using version 1.2.6 (yes it's old, but that's what I'm stuck with currently), I invoke an iframe via a button click (see screenshot below)

[image]

Everything is fine if the user selects a radio button and submits the form. However, if the user closes the fancybox then invokes the iframe again (using the same button click as before), the form is not clickable. Instead there are left and right arrows on the iframe as if it's trying to display a picture (see screenshot below)

[image]

The only way to 'fix' the issue is to reload the page or **not** dismiss the fancybox in the first place.

**[UPDATE]**

Here is how I invoke the fancybox. To dismiss the fancybox, you have to click on the "Modify Address" button.

```
$('#hidden_link').fancybox({
    frameWidth:400,
    frameHeight:500,
    hideOnOverlayClick:false,
    hideOnContentClick:false,
    showCloseButton:false
}).trigger('click');
```

The element `#hiddenlink` is a hidden `href`.

`<a href="/assets/cnt/index.html" style="display:none;" id="hidden_link"></a>`

**[UPDATE 2]**

Firebug displays the error `Image corrupt or truncated: data:image/gif;base64,AAAA` when this occurs. Not sure if that is related or not.

Comment: I don't know Fancybox but it sounds like maybe it doesn't clean up after itself after initializing the first popup (e.g. doesn't remove an iFrame or something). I would suggest taking a look at the before/after state of the app and make sure that they look similar after firing the first box.

Comment: got any link? it seems like the <a> tag is getting a "rel" attribute as other elements in the document after the click. Do you use fancybox for a gallery of images? if so, there is part of your script that is aggregating the link to the form into the gallery  ... but I am just guessing, with a link I could tell you for sure.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Does Fancybox create a container div for the modal on page load, or does it create it on demand? If it creates one on page load then it might offer a "destroy" or "delete" method you can call on close.

If it creates one on demand then you might be able to explicitly destroy the existing one on close.